# Epsilon proof 10

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

Assume for every real number $x$, there is an integer $N$ such that $N>x^3$. Prove that for every positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such  that for all $n\geq N$, $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$

Ok so I know I am suppose to show an attempt or at least explain my thought process, but honestly I don't even know how to start this proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: First step.  Figure out what they are *asking*.  Don't worry about proving, but what, in english, are the asking.

Comment: And thats probably the part I am having difficulty with is understanding what in english they are asking.

Comment: The problem is asking you to show that for every positive real (ie number greater than 0) there is always a smaller 1/n. Even as $\epsilon$ gets close to zero it should make intuitive sense that you can find a large enough n st 1/n is smaller.

Comment: Consider if $\epsilon$ is a positive real number, then $\frac 1{\epsilon}$ is also a positive real number.  Now you are assuming that there is an $N > (\frac 1{\epsilon})^3> 0$.  If $n > N > (\frac 1{\epsilon})^3 > 0$ then $\frac 1n < \frac 1N < \epsilon^3$.  ... Okay, I have to admit the statement of "assume if $x$ is real there is an $N > x^3$" is strange but... if $\epsilon \le 1$ then $\epsilon^3 \le \epsilon$ and if $\epsilon > 1$ then $\frac 1n < 1 < \epsilon$.

Comment: Are you sure you are being asked to prove that if $x$ is real there is an $N > x^3$ and not that there is an $N > x$?  Both are true, but $N > x$ is more straightforward and direct.

Comment: Yes the $x^3$ is not a typo